# Using window.print() to print a different stylesheet without restyling the page?

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I have a print button on my page that will run window.print(), it just prints the page exactly. Is there a way to pass a parameter to that function so that it will print my page with the stylesheet print.css rather than style.css, without necessitating a page refresh?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your css put any print specific CSS rules into

```
@media print{

}
```

And css rules for displaying into

```
@media screen, projection, tv{

}
```

HTML will look this

```
  <link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
```